# How to use multiple criteria for the `find` command

Tags: command-line, bash, find

I have a folder where I keep my untagged music in which I want to launch a script to delete all the PNG and JPG files, except those beginning with the word "cover".

Here's what I tried (I didn't include the `-delete` flag at the end on purpose):

```sh
find . -name '*.jpg' -or -name '*.png' -not - -name 'cover.*'
```

```sh
find . (-name '*.jpg' -or -name '*.png'\) -not - -name '*.png'
```

I have also tried other variations of the above two commands, but none worked.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The command you are looking for is:

```
find . -type f \( -name '*.jpg' -or -name '*.png' \) -not -name "cover.*"
```

- Adding `type -f` will make the `find` command look only for files.
- In your second command, you need to add a space after `\(` and before `\)` (you also forgot `\` before `(`).
- Also, you don't need a `-` between `-not` and `-name`. Your first command works fine if you remove it, although not producing the output that you want (see JoL's [comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1170231/how-to-use-multiple-criteria-for-find/1170236?noredirect=1#comment1953250_1170236)).

You can read more about `find`'s syntax and options at the command's online [Ubuntu manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/find.1.html), or run the command `man find` to read the manual in the terminal. Specifically, read the `OPERATORS` section of the manual, since that's what appears to be confusing you the most.

**Note:** Most terminal commands provide a manual with the proper command syntax and available options which you can read if you run `man <command>` in your terminal.

Comment: "Your first command works fine if you remove it." -- No, it wouldn't. `-a` (which is the default operator when you have 2 adjacent expressions) has higher precedence than `-o`/`-or`. That means the first command would be equivalent to: `find . -name '*.jpg' -or \( -name '*.png' -not -name 'cover.*' \)` which is different.

Comment: You are right. My comment about the first command refers to the OP's statement that none of the commands worked for them, not on the command producing the correct result. I am editing my answer to clarify this. Thank you!

Comment: @JoL The OP's first command was not running due to the `-`.